# change form action on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, button, action

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I invoke multiple actions from a single form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929685/how-can-i-invoke-multiple-actions-from-a-single-form)

i have two buttons in a form. The one is for calculate, the other for send the calculated data in an email. 
So i´ve made `"action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` to calculate the whole thing in the form. Now i want to make the other button change the action to "mail.php" so i´ve made this:

`<input type="submit" name="senden" value="Senden" onClick="document.form.action.value="mailer.php"">`

But we all know, it doesn't work. So how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this.

```
<input type="button" name="senden1" value="Send" onClick="sendMailer()">
<input type="button" name="senden2" value="Calculate" onClick="caclculate()">
```

Then in `calculate` function just calculate the data and when user click `Send` just set the action and submit it in `sendMailer()` .DON'T submit in calculate().

```
 document.<Form_Name>.action = 'mailer.php';
 document.<Form_Name>.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="xxx.php" name="frm1" id="frm1">
    <input type="button" name="senden1" value="Send" onClick="sendMailer()" id="senden1">
</from>
<form action="yyy.php" name="frm2" id="frm2">
<input type="button" name="senden2" value="Calculate" onClick="caclculate()">
</from>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        var form1 =  $("#frm1");
        var form2 =  $("#frm2");
        $("#senden1").click(function(){
               form1.submit(); 
        });
        $("#senden2").click(function(){
                form2.submit(); 
        });

    });
</script>
```